# Re-indexing in PlayOrm

Tags: playorm

In PlayOrm, I have gone through the command line tool classes but not able to figure out if there is a better way to do re-indexing? 
i.e., If I have to re-build an index of any entity, is there a straight forward API or do I need to do what all has been done in cmdline utility? If there is no straight way to do it now, then is it planned for future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "better way"

Right now in command line tool, you can re-index by using the following command

```
REINDEX /<Column Family>/<Indexed Column>/<Partitioned by>/<Partition Id>
```

or if there are no partitions

```
REINDEX /<Column Family>/<Indexed Column>
```

Typically re-indexing is a manual thing.  It can be done through the api since command line does it through an api though I think most people will re-index manually.

Comment: Ok, so do you mean the only way for people to do re-indexing will be through command line?